# Separate a list of spheres into several lists, each contained in a sphere with a radius no larger than specified.

Tags: optimization, algorithms, nonlinear-optimization

I have a list of arbitrary spheres, what I want to end up with is that list separated into a number of groups, where spheres in each group all fit into thier specific larger sphere. The limitation is, the radius of the larger spheres cannot exceed the maximum specified radius.

I can think of a brute force algorithm: loop the list, start building a larger sphere untill it reaches the maxumum radius, check if there are nearer spheres with smaller radiuses that can create a better large sphere, etc. But I need an efficient algorithm, so I wonder if it's a standard problem and has a standard solution I can read about?

P.S. I forgot to mention: spheres are not physical objects, they are abstract concepts with fixed position and radius, but they can be located inside one another or intersect one another.

Comment: This is a truly horrible problem to have to solve. It combines the NP-complete [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) with the NP-hard [unequal sphere-packing problem](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1009831621621).

Comment: Right, :), thanks God it's not a must-do in our project :). TY for the reply, wierdly enough I thout it is simple...

Comment: But, really, I indeed CAN think of a bruteforce solution - the one I roughly described - am I missing something?

Comment: The thing about an NP-complete problem is (roughly) that its solution time is exponential in the length of the input. So on a reasonably large input, any brute-force algorithm will just keep going, like the Energizer Bunny.